Dependency between radio button and toggle
In a SAC story, I am having to functionalities that work on a table:

Switch/Toggle: A toggle to add/remove a measure called 'Adjustment' to the table
Radio button: Two radio buttons to change between the currencies (USD and EUR). This works by adding different measures to the table (e.g. Net Sales (EUR) vs. Net Sales (USD)).

Adjustments are only available in USD. So, I have implemented a functionality that the toggle only works when USD is selected via the radio button. If both options are applied (USD and show adjustments) and the user then selects EUR (radio button), the switch is set to off, cannot be selected and the table should show values in EUR. BUT: The last point (showing values in EUR) does not work. Instead, it shows the table as defined in the toggle function (the line of the code which adds ["Gross_USD","Net_USD" - see below].
The formulas (radio button):
Application.showBusyIndicator("Loading data...");
if (RadioButtonGroup.getSelectedKey() === "USD")
{
Glob_Select_DS.setDimensionFilter(Alias.MeasureDimension,["Net_USD"]);
Switch_show_adjustments.setEnabled(true);
        
}
else if (RadioButtonGroup.getSelectedKey() === "EUR"){  
Switch_show_adjustments.setOn(false);
Switch_show_adjustments.setEnabled(false);  
Glob_Select_DS.setDimensionFilter(Alias.MeasureDimension,["Net_EUR"]);
}
Application.hideBusyIndicator();


Formula toggle:
Application.showBusyIndicator("Loading data...");
if (Switch_show_adjustments.isOn()){
Glob_Select_DS.setDimensionFilter(Alias.MeasureDimension,["Net_USD","Corrections"]);
}else{
Glob_Select_DS.setDimensionFilter(Alias.MeasureDimension,[""Gross_USD","Net_USD"]);
}
Application.hideBusyIndicator();

Does anyone have a solution to fix this?
Thanks upfront!
I tried re-arranging the order of the three lines:
Switch_show_adjustments.setOn(false);
Switch_show_adjustments.setEnabled(false);  
Glob_Select_DS.setDimensionFilter(Alias.MeasureDimension,["Net_EUR"]);

I was expecting that this works, as the last line should be shown.

You have a typo in the line Glob_Select_DS.setDimensionFilter(Alias.MeasureDimension,[""Gross_USD","Net_USD"]);There are two double quotation marks before Gross_USD. Other than that, the logic behind disabling the switch seems to be correct. Have you tested if the commands which set the dimension filters on the Data Source work as expected outside the scripts that you shared here?
